# Python Tkinter label is not displaying correct ASCII values

Tags: python, tkinter

The Hex value is converted into ASCII and displaying through Python tk library.And using Tkinter LabelFrame.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

labelframe = LabelFrame(root, text="")
labelframe.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")

response = '62 F1 11 62 00 00 32 2D 31 34 45 30 39 39 2D 4D 41 30 31'
BResponse = response.replace(' ', '')
BResponse = BResponse.decode('hex')
BResponse = BResponse[3:]

left = Label(labelframe, text="ASCII Conversion::" +' '+ BResponse)
left.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Getting value: only first character.`b`

I am expecting the ASCII conversion `b  2-14E099-MA01`

Is tkinter support the ASCII value?

Comment: Does the value print as expected when you just `print` it? If not, this has nothing to do with Tkinter.

Comment: Yes. I am able to get expected value by just print

Comment: When I print the `repr` of the string, I get `'b\x00\x002-14E099-MA01'`, which seems correct given the two `00` bytes in positions 4 and 5.

Comment: Yes. ASCII of '00' is empty. How can I print now?

Comment: Well, "00" may be "empty", but it's not a space, but a `NULL` byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem does not seem to be related to Tkinter at all. When I print the `repr` of the string, I get `'b\x00\x002-14E099-MA01'`, which seems correct given the two `00` bytes in positions 4 and 5. If you want those to be rendered as space, you could replace them accordingly:

```
>>> BResponse[3:].replace("\x00", " ")
'b  2-14E099-MA01'
```

Update: There seems to have been a sort of misunderstanding: `00` is *not* a space, but a [`NULL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) byte. A space would be `32`, i.e. `20` in Hex (not to be confused with the `32` you have, which is `50`, i.e. `2`).

```
>>> ord(" ")
32
>>> int("32", 16)
50
>>> chr(50)
'2'
```